# How to access a created object in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to work out how the following.

I call a view:

```
var loader = new LoadingView();
```

the function attached to that view this creates a new object 'spinner'

```
loader.showLoader()
```

What I'm now hoping it that I can next call a function that hides that object spinner

```
loader.hideLoader();
```

However, hideLoader does not have access to the 'spinner' object.

Why?

**view code:**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'spinner',
], function($, _, Backbone, Spinner){

  var LoadingView = Backbone.View.extend({
       el: '#loader',
       // View constructor
        initialize: function() {
             this.opts = {
              zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
              top: '20', // Top position relative to parent in px
              left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
            };
            _.bindAll(this, 'showLoader', 'hideLoader');
        },


      showLoader: function () {
        var spinner = new Spinner(this.opts).spin(this.el);
    },

     hideLoader: function () {
         var self = this;
         console.log(self)
      this.spinner.stop();
    }

    }); // end loaderview

return LoadingView;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have defined `spinner` in local scope, it is just a variable in the local scope of `showLoader` and not attached to the `this` context as a property which you are trying to access in `hideLoader`, So try changing it to

```
 showLoader: function () {
        this.spinner = new Spinner(this.opts).spin(this.el); //assuming spin returns the spinner object itself if not. do the below
        //this.spinner = new Spinner(this.opts);
        //this.spinner.spin(this.el);     
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the spinner object as a property of `this`:

```
showLoader: function () {
    this.spinner = new Spinner(this.opts);
    this.spinner.spin(this.el); // not sure if you can chain these calls
},
```